# 'bad substitution' in linux shell scripting

Tags: shell, scripting

```
# !/bin/sh
echo "Enter file name:"
read fname
set ${ls -la $fname}
echo "The size of test.sh is $5 byte"
exit 0
```

I want to make a code which can print file size using 'set' command in linux shell script, so I use ls -la but it doesn't work and my terminal just says 'bad substitution' in line 4 . Any help pls :)

Comment: I think you meant to use `$()`, not `${}`. Not sure what you want to do with the output of `ls` and `set`, though. Perhaps you meant `set -- $(ls -la "$fname")`, but that seems [fragile](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to try the following:

```sh
# !/bin/sh
echo "Enter file name:"
read fname
SIZE=$(ls -l "${fname}" |awk '{print $5}')
echo "The size of ${fname} is ${SIZE} bytes"
exit 0
```

`SIZE` variable will contain the size of the read filename. Please note that `ls -al` as just like `ls -l` but it also shows hidden files (those beginning with '.').

Using `set` to define variables is not really a best practice.
[Here's a suggestion about the usage of set](https://www.lifewire.com/set-linux-command-4095212).

Comment: I thought that wasn't needed once you have brackets, but happy to refine based on good feedback. Thanks!

Comment: The brackets don’t prevent expansion (they’re good for other reasons, but make no difference in this case). Try `a='*' ; echo ${a}` vs `a='*' ; echo "${a}"`.

Answer (score -1):

Following and correcting castel I would rather say:

```sh
# !/bin/sh
read -p "Enter file name: " fname
SIZE=$(ls -l "$fname" | awk '{print $5}')
echo "The size of $fname is $SIZE bytes"
```

Comment: @Biffen: oops, sorry. Also added quotes around the second occurrence of `fname`.